# Does an Operator on $C^2[0,1]$ exist?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, functional-calculus

Assume you have a linear operator $A:C^2[0,1]\rightarrow C^2[0,1]$ s.t.

$(1-A)f(x)=c$ if $f(x)=c$ a constant function, which means $A\mathbb{1}=0$ and $(1-A)\tilde{f}(x)=const.$ (a constant function) if $\tilde{f}$ is not constant. Can we show that such an operator doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator $$Af=f-f(0)$$ satisfies the required assumptions. More generally  for   a probability measure $\mu $  on $[0,1]$ the operator $$Af=f-\int\limits_0^1f(t)\,d\mu(t)$$ satisfies the assumptions.

Comment: Dont know why I went for the overkill with my answer

Comment: @GBA Perhaps the question should be modified somehow to avoid trivial solution. Let's wait for the asker reaction.

Comment: True, i have to modify it. It should be $\forall \tilde{f}\in C^2[0,1]\setminus\mathbb{R}:(1-A)\tilde{f}\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Just adding more context: The above problem is related to the Hille-Yosida Theorem for infinitesimal generators where in [Kallenberg, Foundations of Modern Probability 2021, Thm 17.11] one condition is stated: ii) Range$(\lambda_0-A)$ is dense in $C_0$ for some $\lambda_0>0$. For my specific generator, I know already that $A(1)=0$. And I want to show that $Range(1-A)$ is dense by showing it separates points for the Weierstraße-Stone Theorem.